# Why does django jython connection to a MySQL database give a "Communication Link Failure"?

Tags: python, mysql, django, tomcat, jython

I'm trying to convert a django / cPython app to run as a Tomcat WAR using Jython.  We are using a mysql database (MySQLdb in cPython / mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar in jython).  I have changed the DATABASE_ENGINE between the two configurations.  The app runs great with cPython (after I disabled SELinux limitations on http connections to a database).  The front page, images, and static content work in the jython.  However, when I request a page that hits the database, it seems to hang for a while, then returns with:

> Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to
>   the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The
>   driver has not received any packets
>   from the server. [SQLCode: 0],
>   [SQLState: 08S01]

Has anyone seen this before?  I don't see any recent discussions of this type or problem.  I'm using django 1.2.5, jython 2.5.2.  I've tried running the Java app under Fedora (jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64) and Windows (Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)).  Same behavior.  I've also tried both mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar (the latest version) and mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar ("extensively tested" according to http://packages.python.org/django-jython/database-backends.html).  None of the various configurations affect the behavior.

How can I solve it or where should I look next?

Comment: Did you try to play around with SElinux in context of java <-> mysql?

Comment: not yet, but I haven't seen any messages to suggest that it's denying anything.  I'll try completely disabling it just to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake.  In hindsight, it's obvious.  I made a type-o in the IP address of the database server, but only in the configuration file on the jython branch.  As a result, the Jython instance hung while the cPython instance didn't.  Found the error when I merged the two into a single settings.py (using "if os.name=='java'" to make the necessary jython changes.

So . . . What's the correct protocol here?  Should I delete the question or leave it up in case someone else makes the same type of mistake I did?

Comment: I've decided to leave my error up for the sake of posterity.  I can't be the only one to type-o on an IP address and not notice it.